# Postgresql not binding in prepared statement for SELECT in PHP

Tags: php, postgresql, select, prepared-statement

```
<?php
try 
{
   global $db;
   $user = 'postgres';
   $password = '*****'; //For security
   $db = new PDO('pgsql:host=localhost;dbname=dnd', $user, $password);
   $db->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
}
catch (PDOException $ex)
{
   echo 'ERROR!!: ' . $ex->getMessage();
   die();
}

   $table = htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST['table']);
   $idNum = htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST['id']);

try {
   //$query = "SELECT * FROM $table WHERE id = $idNum";  This works
   //$query = "SELECT * FROM $table WHERE id = :number"; This works 

   $query = "SELECT * FROM :tableName WHERE id = :number";
   $statement = $db->prepare($query);
   $statement->bindValue(":tableName", $table, PDO::PARAM_STR);
   $statement->bindValue(":number", $idNum, PDO::PARAM_INT); 
   $statement->execute();
   $info = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

} catch (PDOException $excep) {
   echo "Opps: " . $excep->getMessage();
   die();
}
```

Okay I'm going crazy here trying to get this to work.
I have a database set up that I need to query from. I receive the query from an AJAX request with the name of the table I want and the id for the item. When I try to query with both variables, the binding does not occur in the prepared statement and instead I get this error code

Opps: SQLSTATE[42601]: Syntax error: 7 ERROR: syntax error at or near "$1" LINE 1: SELECT * FROM $1 WHERE id = 1 ^

When I have just the straight PHP variables it works fine so I know it can work, but when I want to bind multiple it seems to fail and give a variable number as above. 
I can also get it to work if I simply have one of the variables bound, such as the second commented out query in the code - this only works tho if I have the variable I want at the end and not if I wanted to lookup the table spot. (I.E. 
    `$query = "SELECT * FROM :tableName WHERE id = $idNum"; does not work)`
I need to cleanse the variables to prevent SQL injection, but I can't do that without binding the variables in a prepared statement. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the PHP manual you can't bind a tablename. As you mentioned it, you can replace it by a variable, but you can't replace it with a placeholder.

So the only solution that will work for you is the query you have above:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM $table WHERE id = :number"
```

This will be what you're looking for. If you want to make it safe for injection, you have to find another way. (Regex for example).

Ref: https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php#69304